# kafka + what is the meaning of Log directory is offline

Tags: linux, hard-drive, kafka

our Kafka production cluster include **23 broker machines** , and each broker include **35** JBOD disks

broker version is - apache 2.7 version , and cluster include 5 zookeeper servers

from `/var/log/kafka/server.log` we seen many warning like the following

```
Log directory /var/kafka/broker_logsXX is offline
```

or here are few examples from `server.log`

```
[2023-09-22 02:10:34,583] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=1012] Unable to describe replica dirs for /var/kafka/broker_logs3 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Log directory /var/kafka/broker_logs3 is offline
[2023-09-22 02:10:34,588] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=1012] Unable to describe replica dirs for /var/kafka/broker_logs24 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Log directory /var/kafka/broker_logs24 is offline
[2023-09-22 02:10:34,588] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=1012] Unable to describe replica dirs for /var/kafka/broker_logs9 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Log directory /var/kafka/broker_logs9 is offline
[2023-09-22 02:10:34,594] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=1012] Unable to describe replica dirs for /var/kafka/broker_logs39 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Log directory /var/kafka/broker_logs39 is offline





[2023-11-03 09:52:46,390] INFO Updated cache from existing <empty> to latest FinalizedFeaturesAndEpoch(features=Features{}, epoch=1). (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureCache)
[2023-11-03 09:52:46,393] INFO Cluster ID = XXXXXXXXXXX (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-11-03 09:52:46,724] ERROR Fail to read meta.properties under log directory /var/kafka/broker_logs24 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/kafka/broker_logs24/meta.properties.tmp: Input/output error
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:244)
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
        at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
        at kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint.read(BrokerMetadataCheckpoint.scala:69)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.$anonfun$getBrokerMetadataAndOfflineDirs$1(KafkaServer.scala:784)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.$anonfun$getBrokerMetadataAndOfflineDirs$1$adapted(KafkaServer.scala:782)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.getBrokerMetadataAndOfflineDirs(KafkaServer.scala:782)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:246)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

not clearly why Kafka broker is complains about  Log directory `/var/kafka/....` is offline ?

is it because disk problem ? or high load on disk ? or maybe broker not sync to target replica ? , etc.

on the last example we can see

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/kafka/broker_logs24/meta.properties.tmp: Input/output error
```

from my understanding `input/output` errors is maybe typical disk problem

but when I look on all 35 broker machine we can see about 4-6 warning about  `Log directory /var/kafka/... is offline`

so its not make sense that each broker has 4-6 faulty disks ?

Comment: I am having a similar problem where certain replicas are failing because of an error indicating that the replica log directory is offline. Did you figure out the root cause of this problem that you're having?